# Add Custom Meta Details to wp_get_sites() in WP Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

How can I add meta data to wordpress sites such that the meta are returned on wp_get_sites()  or get_blog_list() function. Currently this is what is returned:

```
{
            "blog_id": "1",
            "domain": "example.com",
            "path": "/",
            "site_id": "1",
            "registered": "2022-02-02 22:15:59",
            "last_updated": "2022-07-08 17:05:55",
            "public": "1",
            "archived": "0",
            "mature": "0",
            "spam": "0",
            "deleted": "0",
            "lang_id": "0"
        },
```

Or is there a table where I can add my own meta or site information that will be returned alongside the object above, e.g. "blog_currency": "USD", etc...

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site_query/__construct/

Comment: Thanks Howard. I saw this, however, I tried update_site_meta( $site_id, $meta_key, $meta_value); but it doesn't add anything to the wp_get_sites() object. What is the hook I need to update_site_meta that will achieve that

Comment: You can try with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_site_option/